# Street view on Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps

I try to offer 3 display modes to users of my app:

Traffic View (the standard view as on every printed map)
Satellite View (aerial) and
StreetView (3D, as done with the infamous Google Car)

I can set 'Standard' traffic view with

```
            mapView.setSatellite(false);
            mapView.setTraffic(true);
```

Satellite view with

```
            mapView.setSatellite(true);
```

but

```
            mapView.setStreetView(true);
```

doesn't do anything, even if I can get StreetView at the location checking with maps.google.com and a followup check for mapView.isStreetView() returns TRUE.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: `setStreetView(true)` should load a tile set showing streets where StreetView data is available. It will not, however, actually display StreetView itself -- that is a separate application.

Comment: I think this pretty much answers my question, thanks! I don't know how to proceed now, since I can't tag the question as "solved" now as you posted your answer as comment?!

Comment: It wasn't clear to me if my comment truly hit your problem, or you were not even getting the tile set, which is why I had posted it as a comment originally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setStreetView(true)` should load a tile set showing streets where StreetView data is available. It will not, however, actually display StreetView itself -- that is a separate application. You can launch StreetView, for devices that have it, for a given location [by using a specific `Intent` structure](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html). However, you cannot embed StreetView in your own app at this time.